# Why call-by-name parameter expect parameter of type Int instead of () => Int

Tags: scala, callbyname

I'm a little bit confused about using call-by-name parameters in Scala. Please help me to understand what is going on here. Consider the following example of using call-by-name parameter:

```
  def param = {println("Param evaluates"); 40}
  def lazyEval(x: => Int) = {
    println("lazy"); 
    x 
  }
  val s = lazyEval(param + 2)
  // s = 42
```

I have several question related to each other about this:

1. `lazyEval` method expects parameter of type `=> Int`, so why `param + 2` operation is legal? Why we can add integer 2  to object with type `=> Int` (im my understanding under the hood it is `<function0>`) when calling `lazyEval` method? As IDE hints me, the `lazyEval` function expects parameter of type `Int` instead of `=> Int` (what the hell?).
2. Why after changing callback type from `=> Int` to `() => Int`code doesn't compile? Is this 2 types are different? I though the short version ('=> Int') is just a syntactical sugar.
3. After some playing with code, I finally could change code so it will compile with `() => Int`. This way is more intuitive for me.

.

```
  def param = {println("Param evaluates"); 40}
  def lazyEval(x: () => Int) = { // changed type to '() => Int'
    println("lazy"); 
    x() // explicitly calling function using parentheses '()'
  }    
  val s = lazyEval(param _) // adding underscore after method name and removing `+2`
```

What is differences between this version and first one (with callback `=> Int` type)? Why in this version we can't make addition of integer with value `2` and the `param` function (I mean this`lazyEval(param _ + 2)`)? And what mean underscore after method name? (I guess it used to pass method itself, not it return value)

Thanks in help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so why param + 2 operation is legal? Why we can add integer 2 to object with type => Int

We can add `2` to `param` because it evaluates to `Int`, you're adding `Int` with `Int`. `param` isn't a function `=> Int`, it is a method, so `param + 2` *is* `=> Int`. ie. an expression that evaluates to `Int`.

> Why after changing callback type from => Int to () => Intcode doesn't compile? Is this 2 types are different? I though the short version ('=> Int') is just a syntactical sugar.

`=> Int` and `() => Int` don't mean the same thing. One is anything that evaluates to `Int`, and the other a function from `Unit` to `Int`. `2` isn't a `() => Int`, but `() => 2` is. Or you could also say `2` is `=> Int`.

> Why in this version we can't make addition of integer with value 2 and the param function (I mean thislazyEval(param _ + 2))? And what mean underscore after method name? (I guess it used to pass method itself, not it return value)

`param` is a method, not a function. The underscore in this case lifts `param` into a function. So `param _` is a function `() => Int`. And that's exactly why we can't add `2` to it, because you can't add `2` to a function. Basically the exact reason why you think (1) shouldn't work.

---

In summary:

`def lazyEval(x: => Int)` is a method with a parameter `x` that can be *anything that evaluates to `Int`*. That could be any method that returns `Int`, a concrete value of `Int`, or some block of code that resolves to `Int`, etc.

`lazyEval(x: () => Int)` is a method with a parameter `x` that can *only* be a parameterless function that returns `Int`. That could mean the method `param` lifted to a function, or something weird like `() => 2`. But it *must* be a function. So simply passing a value like `2` cannot work.

Comment: I don't know why you'd say that `=> Int` is not a type or that it is mere syntax.

Comment: @som-snytt I awoke at 4:30am after dreaming about writing this answer, and frantically checked it from my phone to find your freshly made comment. Naturally, I remoted into my work computer from my phone to use the REPL and check it out, since I couldn't possibly go back to sleep without knowing. Now that I'm in a more lucid state, I've corrected my answer to not say such incorrect things about `=> Int`.

Comment: Ha. It sounds like SO is working like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

As @m-z has pointed out, `value: => T` can be thought of as a *syntax* for creating a *method* that wraps a given *expression*:

```
object Magician {
  def magic(param: => Int) = param
}

object App {
  val result: Int = Magician.magic(3 + 3)
}
```

translates (roughly) to:

```
object App {
    private[this] def magic$param$1: Int = 3 + 3
    val result: Int = Magician.magic(magic$param$1 _)
}
```

The *behavior* of a call-by-name parameter is similar to a parameterless method definition - referencing either results in the method being called:

```
def paramlessMethod = 3 + 3
def callByName(param: => Int) = param + paramlessMethod
def test() = callByName(5 + 5) //  16, always
```

In both cases, you can "lift" the method to a `Function0` (or "defer the evaluation of the method" if you prefer to think of it that way) by using the magic `_`:

```
def paramlessMethod = 3 + 3
val functionWrapper: Function0[Int] = paramlessMethod _
functionWrapper() // 6

def callByName(param: => Int) = param _
val functionFromParam: Function0[Int] = callByName(3 + 3)
functionFromParam() // 6
```

Comment: I don't know why you'd say that `=> Int` is not a type or that it is mere syntax.

Comment: @som-snytt - I wouldn't say that it does not have a type - but the type is not one that you can create in any other way (it's a type internal to the compiler).  So I decided, rather than focus on the typeness of `=> T` to try presenting it as a syntactical transformation, to see if that aided understanding.

Comment: I see what you mean, but you can overload on `f(i: Int)` and `f(i: => Int)`, so it's not theoretical or an implementation artifact. It's a real type. The fact that you can't use it in a type ascription like `f(42: => Int)` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `def i: Int` is explained here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#method-types

The type of a by-name parameter `i: => Int` is explained here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters

> The type of such a parameter is then the parameterless method type =>
>   T.

In other words, it is the same as the method type `def i: Int`.